# Mouse hovering makes text and icons in the top bar to disappear from the website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I wrote the below code into additional CSS on my WordPress website and the background changed to blue with white font. So far it's good but when I hover upon the text and icons they vanish and reappear when the mouse does not hover.

```
/* TOP BAR COLOR */
.top-bar {
    background-color: #2874f0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.widget ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.social-links li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.top-bar li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}


/* MAIN MENU FONT COLOR */
.main-navigation a {
color: #2874f0;
}
```

Comment: Is your main-navigation inside top bar?

Comment: Probably there is a `.top-bar:hover {…` somewhere in the original WordPress CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.top-bar,
.top-bar:hover {
    background-color: #2874f0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```